# Tensorflow loss value seemingly unrelated to calculated loss

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I just have a question on how the loss value which is displayed next to the progress bar when training a tensorflow model is calculated. In my model, I am using a custom loss function. If I enable eager execution and print out the loss of this custom error function in every training step, this printed value is completely different from the loss value reported next to the progress bar. How can that be? The values are even in a completely different order of magnitude.

Here is a quick example of the progress bar and the printed loss tensor next to it:

```
tf.Tensor([0.31937614], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
  1/589 [..............................] - ETA: 1:49 - loss: 15.5015  tf.Tensor([0.1574446], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
  2/589 [..............................] - ETA: 37s - loss: 24.6688   tf.Tensor([0.15735555], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
  3/589 [..............................] - ETA: 37s - loss: 24.7088  tf.Tensor([0.19418842], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
  4/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 20.4601  tf.Tensor([0.15759456], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
  5/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 17.2965  tf.Tensor([0.15744878], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
  6/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 15.4776  tf.Tensor([0.15758634], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
  7/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 13.9436  tf.Tensor([0.16282028], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
  8/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 12.8040  tf.Tensor([0.15744457], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
  9/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 11.8234  tf.Tensor([0.15738101], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
 10/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 11.0480  tf.Tensor([0.15851957], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
 11/589 [..............................] - ETA: 37s - loss: 10.4038  tf.Tensor([0.16640095], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
 12/589 [..............................] - ETA: 37s - loss: 9.9043   tf.Tensor([0.15737341], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
 13/589 [..............................] - ETA: 37s - loss: 9.4801  tf.Tensor([0.16393052], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
 14/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 9.0843  tf.Tensor([0.15737893], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
 15/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 8.7705  tf.Tensor([0.16211464], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
 16/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 8.4443  tf.Tensor([0.15996283], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
 17/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 8.1412  tf.Tensor([0.160301], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
 18/589 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 7.8582  tf.Tensor([0.15839458], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: This has been asked many times before, the loss you see in the progress bar is an exponential average of per-batch losses, it will not match with each per-batch loss.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your answer is not correct though, since the values in an exponential average still need to be about the same as the actual values. But here we see (as I explicitly stated above) that the values are in a completely different order of magnitude. Luckily I just found the error: I still had a regularization term in my model that I was not aware of, which added a lot to the overall error.

Comment: This answers the question, not necessarily your problem, you asked what value was printed. And we have no idea what value you are printing or how.